# OpsWorks: Cookbook httpd not found on recipe run

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, berkshelf, aws-opsworks

I've just started working with Chef and OpsWorks on AWS in an effort to improve our infrastructure.

I'm running into some problems when attempting to run a recipe that I've set up to do (I think) some pretty basic things (setting up httpd and such).

I keep running into problems with including recipes though before the configuration stuff actually gets to run.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/Tokeniser/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
----------------------------------
Cookbook httpd not found. If you're loading httpd from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/Tokeniser/recipes/default.rb:12:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/Tokeniser/recipes/default.rb:

5:  # Copyright (C) 2016 YOUR_NAME
6:  #
7:  # All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
8:  #
9:  
10:  include_recipe("deploy")
11:  include_recipe("php")
12>> include_recipe("httpd")
13:  
14:  package 'apache2' do
15:    case node[:platform]
16:    when 'centos','redhat','fedora','amazon'
17:      package_name 'httpd'
18:    when 'debian','ubuntu'
19:      package_name 'apache2'
20:    end
21:    action :install
```

This is after I already have a `berksfile` in my root that consists of:

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

metadata

cookbook 'httpd', '~> 0.3.3'
cookbook 'php', '~> 1.7.2'
cookbook 'magic_shell', '~> 1.0.0'
cookbook 'composer', '~> 2.2.1'
```

The failure log even notes the `httpd` recipe being fetched:

```
[2016-01-20T16:18:17+00:00] INFO: 
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'Tokeniser' from source at .
Fetching cookbook index from https://supermarket.chef.io...
Using Tokeniser (0.1.0) from source at .
Installing build-essential (2.2.4) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing chef-sugar (3.3.0) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing chef_handler (1.2.0) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing compat_resource (12.5.26) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing composer (2.2.1) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing httpd (0.3.3) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing iis (4.1.5) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing magic_shell (1.0.0) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing mysql (6.1.2) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing php (1.7.2) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing rbac (1.0.3) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing smf (2.2.7) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing windows (1.39.1) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing xml (2.0.0) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing yum (3.9.0) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing yum-epel (0.6.5) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Installing yum-mysql-community (0.1.21) from https://supermarket.chef.io ([opscode] https://supermarket.chef.io:443/api/v1)
Vendoring Tokeniser (0.1.0) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/Tokeniser
Vendoring build-essential (2.2.4) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/build-essential
Vendoring chef-sugar (3.3.0) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/chef-sugar
Vendoring chef_handler (1.2.0) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/chef_handler
Vendoring compat_resource (12.5.26) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/compat_resource
Vendoring composer (2.2.1) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/composer
Vendoring httpd (0.3.3) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/httpd
Vendoring iis (4.1.5) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/iis
Vendoring magic_shell (1.0.0) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/magic_shell
Vendoring mysql (6.1.2) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/mysql
Vendoring php (1.7.2) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/php
Vendoring rbac (1.0.3) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/rbac
Vendoring smf (2.2.7) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/smf
Vendoring windows (1.39.1) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/windows
Vendoring xml (2.0.0) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/xml
Vendoring yum (3.9.0) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/yum
Vendoring yum-epel (0.6.5) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/yum-epel
Vendoring yum-mysql-community (0.1.21) to /opt/aws/opsworks/current/berkshelf-cookbooks/yum-mysql-community
```

And as you can see `php` is also required but it doesn't error there.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm probably being an idiot. Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: httpd 0.3.3 doesn't have a recipe to include. That's probably it. Check https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/httpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer to this was that I was running on OpsWorks' Chef 12 version, which doesn't use Berkshelf on the server and requires you to package you cookbooks using `berks package`, rather than loading from a git repo, unless you only have one cookbook or don't use berkshelf to manage dependancies.

The Amazon documentation is tricky to find but is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-packaging-cookbooks-locally.html

Answer (score 2):

IIUYC you need to add the `http` cookbook dependency to the `Tokeniser` cookbook *metadata.rb* file, not to the Berksfile:

```ruby
# Tokeniser/metadata.rb

 depends 'httpd', '~> 0.3.3'
```

The same applies to the `php` and `deploy` cookbooks, remember to put them in the metadata file.

Comment: Berksfile will be required as well if fetching from external (supermarket)